# I have a class that is supposed to act as a collection of objects with properties. Can I call a function when those properties are accessed?

Tags: python, oop

I'm writing code to control a motor driver.

The driver has one sleep pin, but controls multiple motors. Here's a pared down version of what I have:

```
class motor:
    def __init__(self, pin, etc):
        self._duty = 0

    @property
    def duty(self):
        return self._duty

    @duty.setter(self, duty):
        new_duty = min(1023, max(0, int(duty * 1024)))
        self._duty = new_duty


class driver:
    def __init__(self, pins, etc):
        self.motors = {'A': motor(pin), 'B': motor(pin)}
        self.sleep = Pin(30)
        self.sleep.off()
```

I'd like to have the driver sleep when the motors are unused. In other words, if and only if the `duty` of every motor is `0`, set sleep.on(), otherwise set sleep.off().

Is there a way for my driver class to check the duty of everything in self.motors{} when I run something like `driver.motors['A'].duty = 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are going to be adding logic I think your best bet would be to have an api for setting and getting the motors.

This has the added benefit that if you want to change how you store motors in future versions you don't have to track down all the usages.

```py
class Driver:
    def __init__(self, pins, etc):
        self._motors = {'A': motor(pin), 'B': motor(pin)}
        ...
    def get_motor(self, motor_name):
        # additional logic
        return self._motors[motor_name]
    
    def set_motor(self, motor_name, pin):
        # check if all motors are 0 and go to sleep
```

I put a capital for the class name as that follows Python's [style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Tested and works! I didn't think the returned object would be callable, but I can indeed access `driver.motors['A'].duty = 0` even if driver.motors is a property.

Comment: I've decided to use callbacks instead to do this, but I'll keep this marked as the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

We can add a property - `n_running_motors` to `driver` class which keeps track of how many motors are running and a `driver` object property (`driver_obj` - you should capitalize class names btw) to `motor` class (which stores driver object which runs it).

```py
class motor:
    def __init__(self, pin, driver_obj, etc):
        self._duty = 0
        self.driver_obj = driver_obj

    @property
    def duty(self):
        return self._duty

    @duty.setter(self, duty):
        new_duty = min(1023, max(0, int(duty * 1024)))
        self._duty = new_duty
        if self._duty == 0:
            self.driver_obj.motor_stopped()
        



class driver:
    def __init__(self, pins, etc):
        self.motors = {'A': motor(pin, self, etc), 'B': motor(pin, self, etc)}
        self.sleep = Pin(30)
        self.sleep.off()
        self.n_running_motors = len(self.motors)

    def motor_stopped(self):
    # You can use setter here as well instead of this function.
        self.n_running_motors -= 1
        if self.n_running_motors == 0:    
            sleep.on()
        else:
            # Anytime duty is changed from all 0s to non-zero for
            # any motor, this else block will 'wake up' the driver.
            # Depending upon application, this block may not be necessary.
            sleep.off()
```

Comment: Using polling is not a good solution. I already specified when I want the check to occur: When I change the duty.

Comment: @Kevin sorry I missed that, I will edit my solution.